# Getting typeahead.js to work with dynamic content, Bottle and Hogan

Tags: jquery, bottle, typeahead.js, hogan.js

**Expected Behaviour**

The search field should display results like the 'Open Source Projects by Twitter' example on:

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

**Current Behaviour**

- No drop down is appearing when I enter search text.
- No errors in Firebug.
- All necessary 'container' divs seem to be loaded (but hidden with `display:none`) beneath the search field.
- Results are not generated or displayed.
- `Firebug > Net` DOES display GET request for json file when loading content, and the contents are available in the response tab.

**Troubleshooting**

**Dynamic Content**

Site content is loaded dynamically via getJSON().

**Hogan and typeahead Scripts Are Included In Head**

```
<script src="https://path/to/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://path/to/hogan-2.0.0.js"></script>
```

**Bottle and Hogan**

I use Bottle which also uses the default placeholder used by Hogan ie `{{value here}}`.

So in Hogan.js, i changed the default delimeters from:

```
otag = '{{',
ctag = '}}';
```

to:

```
otag = '[[',
ctag = ']]';
```

**Function**

I created a function that would run after the dynamic content is loaded:

```
<script>
function getTypeAheadReady() {
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead({                              
name: 'mygreatsearch',
valueKey: 'my_field_one',  
prefetch: 'https://path/to/static/courses.json',
template: [
'<p class="my-field-1">[[my_field_one]]</p>',
'<p class="my-field-2">[[my_field_two]]</p>',
'<p class="my-field-3">[[my_field_three]]</p>'
].join(''),
engine: Hogan  
})
}
</script>
```

**Call**

```
$("#content").html("");
$("#content").append(results.content);
getTypeAheadReady(); // re-initialise typeahead.js functionality for search
```

**JSON**

My JSON file seems to be correct:

```
[
{ "my_field_one": "val1", "my_field_two": "val2", "my_field_three": "val3". "tokens":["something"] },
{ "my_field_one": "val4", "my_field_two": "val5", "my_field_three": "val6", "tokens":["somethingelse"] },
]
```

It is located at `https://path/to/static/courses.json` and I can access it directly in the browser.

**HTML** (loaded from database)

```
<div class="example example-twitter-oss">
<div class="demo">
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder 'text'">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

And CSS seems to be correct:

```
.tt-dropdown-menu {
  text-align: left;
}

.title,
.my-field-1 {
  font-family: Prociono;
}

.title {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.example {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.course-title {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.demo {
  position: relative;
  *z-index: 1;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
  width: 396px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
      border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
}

.typeahead {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}

.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}

.tt-dropdown-menu {
  width: 422px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
      border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}

.example-twitter-oss .tt-suggestion {
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

.example-twitter-oss .tt-suggestion + .tt-suggestion {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.example-twitter-oss .my-field-2 {
  float: right;
  font-style: italic;
}

.example-twitter-oss .my-field-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.example-twitter-oss .my-field-3 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Great question, with all this data can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't think I could replicate the scenario as it draws data from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Stray comma after second object in .json file.

Comment: And (in the same file) a period where a comma should be, after `"val3"`